# Using C++'s namespace{} sort-of like C#'s #region/#endregion

Tags: c++, ide, namespaces, cross-platform, code-generation

I work on a C++ project that runs on Windows, Mac and Linux. As a result it's not uncommon to be working on the same part of code in Visual Studio one day, Xcode the next, Qt Creator the next, etc.

Lately I have taken to using the namespace{} keyword in much the same way that #region/#endregion are used in C#. For example:

```
// MyFile.cpp

namespace MyNamespace
{
  // lots of code related to one class
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
  // lots of code related to another class
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
  // lots of code related to yet another class
}
```

While this doesn't allow me to name the regions per say, I still find it very helpful being able to collapse large chunks of code. I know that IDE-specific solutions exist, such as `#pragma region/#pragma endregion` but I was unable to find a way that was IDE agnostic for C++. Also, I know that these large chunks could be put in their own files, but for the purposes of this question please assume that this is not an option.

My question is: does this create any overhead in the compiled binaries? Can doing this impact performance negatively or impact the end result (binary) at all?

*(Note: We use Microsoft's compiler on Windows, clang on Mac and gcc on Linux.)*

Thank you!

Comment: My assumption is there isn't since if these namespaces were put into their own files, the pre-compiled code result would be nearly the same. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: I think the OP meant that all the regions are in the same file, to use "folding" in editors and IDEs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your questions are "no". Follow long answers:

> does this create any overhead in the compiled binaries?

No. Assuming you were already using the namespaces, the impact is absolutely zero. If you *weren't* previously using the namespace, there is a small impact in the size of the mangled identifiers to link.

This:

```
void identifier() {}        
namespace longnamespace { void identifier() {} }
```

Become the symbols `_Z10identifierv` and `_ZN13longnamespace10identifierv`, respectively. If you have a **huge** project, with **hundreds of thousands** of symbols, it may affect (albeit slightly) your link time and your dynamic-link (loading) time.

> Can doing this impact performance negatively or impact the end result
>   (binary) at all?

Yes, at least in terms of loading times. But not a lot. And there *are* solutions to mitigate it (google for "prelink" and "prebinding").

Comment: I should have mentioned that the ``MyNamespace`` namespace is already being used throughout the project.